# LIST element derivation

Tags: xml, xsd

Climbing up the XML learning curve, I've slipped on a Validation issue with the use of the `list` element. I'm attempting to create a `list` element that would allow only a specific `key`'s values as members.

A little context to help you model what follows. We have a variety of `SOURCE`s each with unique `NAME`. The `NAME` format is restricted by a pattern in a simpleType element; `REFDESType`. The `NAME` uniqueness is enforced by key `source_key`.

Now, attempts to make productive use of this `source_key` to provide input limits on related data fields are not yet yielding the intended results. `POWERSOURCE` is one of these intended usage fields and is the child to element `MODE`. The intent is for `POWERSOURCE` to be capable of `list`ing one or more of the `SOURCE NAME`s but fails MSXML parse. {OK, welcome back after picking yourself up off the floor laughing.} Yes, this is being developed for a standalone EXCEL 2013 based app without 3rd party libraries.

One issue that seems to be glaring (to me anyway) is that `REFDESType` trees into `POWERSOURCE` from two directions. Once thru `NAME` and again thru `REFDESList`. Hmm...

The Parse Error: **The `keyref` 'GEN-1 GEN-2 GEN-3 GEN-4' does not resolve to a `key` for the Identity Constraint '{http://www.myCo.com}source_key'.**

Certainly, the utility of using `list` is apparent to me. Now, if I could only understand how this way is not working. Alternatives approaches are also welcome.

ELA.XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.myCo.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ela="http://www.myCo.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="DB">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="ela:SOURCE" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="ela:MODE" minOccurs="6" maxOccurs="13"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:key name="source_key">
            <xs:selector xpath="ela:SOURCE"/>
            <xs:field xpath="ela:NAME"/>
        </xs:key>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="SOURCE" type="ela:SOURCEType"/>
    <xs:element name="NAME" type="ela:REFDESType"/>
    <xs:element name="MODE" type="ela:MODEType"/>
    <xs:element name="POWERSOURCE" type="ela:REFDESList">
        <xs:keyref name="powersource_ref" refer="ela:source_key">
            <xs:selector xpath="."/>
            <xs:field xpath="."/>
        </xs:keyref>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="REFDESList">
        <xs:list itemType="ela:REFDESType"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="REFDESType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="2"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="9"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]([A-Z0-9;&#32;&#45;]){1,8}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="MODEType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="ela:POWERSOURCE"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="SOURCEType" mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="ela:NAME"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

sample.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ela:DB xmlns:ela="http://www.myCo.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.myCo.com ELA.xsd">
    <ela:SOURCE>
        <ela:NAME>GEN-1</ela:NAME>
    </ela:SOURCE>
    <ela:SOURCE>
        <ela:NAME>GEN-2</ela:NAME>
    </ela:SOURCE>
    <ela:SOURCE>
        <ela:NAME>GEN-3</ela:NAME>
    </ela:SOURCE>
    <ela:SOURCE>
        <ela:NAME>GEN-4</ela:NAME>
    </ela:SOURCE>
    <ela:MODE>
        <ela:POWERSOURCE>GEN-1 GEN-2 GEN-3 GEN-4</ela:POWERSOURCE>
    </ela:MODE>
</ela:DB>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your keyref says that the value as a whole (that is "GEN-1 GEN-2 GEN-3 GEN-4") must match some key value.

I don't think there's any way with keyref to achieve the same effect as the IDREFS type where each item in the list must satisfy the integrity constraint individually. You would need to use XSD 1.1 assertions for this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to match individual list members with keys, only the full list. In your XML file, the value of `<ela:POWERSOURCE>` is a list with four items. However, there is no `<ela:NAME>` to match that value (i.e. a list with the same four items).

Another problem with your schema is that the `xs:keyref` references a `xs:key` that is defined in an ancestor, which is not allowed. The referenced key must be defined in the same element declaration, or in a descendant of the element.

## Modern solution with key and keyref

A possible solution with key constraints is to use dedicated elements for each list item:

```
<ela:MODE>
    <ela:POWERSOURCE>
        <ela:NAME>GEN-1</ela:NAME>
        <ela:NAME>GEN-2</ela:NAME>
        <ela:NAME>GEN-3</ela:NAME>
        <ela:NAME>GEN-4</ela:NAME>
    </ela:POWERSOURCE>
</ela:MODE>
```

In the schema, you could then simply change the `REFDESList` type to:

```
<xs:complexType name="REFDESList">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="ela:NAME" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

And move the keyref to the same element as the key:

```
<xs:element name="DB">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="ela:SOURCE" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element ref="ela:MODE" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="13"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:key name="source_key">
        <xs:selector xpath="ela:SOURCE"/>
        <xs:field xpath="ela:NAME"/>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:keyref name="powersource_ref" refer="ela:source_key">
        <xs:selector xpath="ela:MODE/ela:POWERSOURCE/ela:NAME"/>
        <xs:field xpath="."/>
    </xs:keyref>
</xs:element>
```

## Legacy solution with ID and IDREFS

As [@Michael Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415448/michael-kay) mentioned, there is a legacy mechanism
using the [xs:ID](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#ID) and
[xs:IDREFS](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#IDREFS) types.
To apply them to your schema, remove the `xs:key` and `xs:keyref` elements, and replace the supertype of `REFDESType`:

```
<xs:simpleType name="REFDESType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:ID"> <!-- Restrict legacy ID type -->
        <xs:minLength value="2"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="9"/>
        <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]([A-Z0-9;&#32;&#45;]){1,8}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Now, the value of a `<ela:NAME>` element is a subtype of ID, and can be referenced by values of type IDREF or IDREFS:

```
<xs:element name="POWERSOURCE" type="xs:IDREFS"/> <!-- List of ID references -->
```

The adjusted XSD should validate your XML file, if the used tool conforms to the standard. Note however that the standard [recommends
that ID and IDREFS are only used for attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#ID), i.e.

```
<ela:NAME id="GEN-1"/>
...
<ela:POWERSOURCE ref="GEN-1 GEN-2 GEN-3 GEN-4"/>
```

Comment: TY @Mayer and @Michael Kay. Due to Excel's inherent maxOccurs limitation when importing/exporting to/from ListObject tables I was attempting to improve upon the multi POWERSOURCE elements, i.e., collapse them into a single element `list` and then apply the technique to the rest of the model . Alas, the constraint of being bound to the XSD 1.0 version. Sigh...

Comment: I think we need additional review of my OP. Rationale is that the [`list`][1] example in the W3C site specifically illustrates the use of unique values in the implementation of the `list` named USStates. The USStates list in the W3C example is derived from element USState which is populated by enumeration with all 50, unique state abbreviations.

[1]: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#ListDt

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your comment.
A list contains items, separated by spaces.
List items are simple types and can be restricted as such.
This has nothing to do with key constraints or uniqueness.
Key constraints can only match *entire* lists, not individual list items.

Comment: As @Michael Kay mentioned, there is a special legacy mechanism
using IDREFS. I have elaborated on this in my answer.

Comment: Hello again @Meyer and thank you for continuing this conversation. 
The suggested `ID` and `IDREFS` work as advertised. TY and @Michael Kay both for this knowledge.

I'm still puzzled however about the W3C list example named USStateList. It represents a list of 50 values that by definition of enumeration from USState are each unique. I feel like I'm missing some subtlety about the W3C example. hmm.....

Comment: In the XSD primer example the valid values for items in the list are enumerated in the schema, whereas you want them to appear in the instance document. So it's a completely different requirement. A very reasonable requirement, I would say, but not one that XSD allows for.

Comment: Great to hear. In the W3C example, `USStateList` simply
requires that each list item has to be a valid `USState` value.
There can be any number of items in the list. `NY`, `NY CA`,
or `NY CA PA` are all valid lists, because each item is a valid `USState` value. Note that items can appear multiple times, as illustrated in the example with `<sixStates>PA NY CA NY LA AK</sixStates>`, where NY appears twice.

Comment: Yes, I see that allowed repetition as well. I'll keep playing with this until my need/want/desire to ensure that 1) an instance `list` can be populated from uniquely constrained values from another instance field AND 2) that the list's members themselves are not repeated within the `list` (simto USStateList though recognizing that USStateList does so by the inheritance mechanism via enumeration within the Schema rather than the XML instance document).
Thru this exchange my knowledge of `list`, `key`, `keyref`, `ID`, `IDREF`, and `IDREFS` has increased.

Answer (score 0):

@Michael Kay, @Meyer;

Unless I'm missing something (**and it turns out that I was**), it turns out that the IDREFS suggestion does NOT work with MSXML after all (**unless you dispose of the list element within the simpleType altogether**). It works fine in the XMLSpy development tool but once the schema is attempting to be loaded into Excel 2013 via `SchemaCollection.Add` method it throws this error.

> List datatype must be derived from an atomic datatype or a union of
>   atomic datatypes.

This error message seems contradictory to the 'reported' MSXML [LIST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256162(v=vs.110).aspx) element definition for `itemType` which is...

> The name of a built-in data type or simpleType element defined in this
>   schema (or another schema indicated by the specified namespace). The
>   simpleType element containing the list element is derived from the
>   simple type specified by the list value. The list value must be a
>   qualified name (QName). The use of the simpleType element child and
>   the itemType attribute is mutually exclusive.

I believe my schema meets the LIST requirements. "SOURCENAMEType" is the originating simpleType from which the LIST simpleType "IDREFListType" is derived.
ORIGINAL XML:
    
        
            
            
            A-Z{1,8}"/>

```
<xs:simpleType name="IDREFListType">
    <xs:list itemType="xs:IDREFS"/>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="SOURCELIST" type="ela:IDREFListType"/>
```

**REVISED VERSION THAT ACTUALLY WORKS:** I'm re-writing this as generic XML so that it can be easily copied and re-used. Notice that myLISTType does NOT contain any xs:list element even though that is exactly how it will function. Reason is due to the plural form of atomic element that populates it, i.e., xs:IDREFS which is already a Collection element. In MSXML they apparently do away with declaring the list element (in this type of case) so that their parser does not interpret it as a list of lists which according to the W3C is not permitted. (My supposition based on extensive testing.) Trouble is, I don't find this little nuance documented anywhere. Augh!!!

```
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.myCo.com" xmlns:pfx="http://www.myCo.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="IDNAME" type="pfx:myIDNAMEType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="myLIST" type="pfx:myLISTType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="myIDNAMEType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:ID">
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]([A-Z0-9;&#32;&#45;]){1,8}"/>
            <!-- pattern for illustrative purposes only, not req'd -->
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="myLISTType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:IDREFS">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="4"/>
            <!-- min/max for illustrative purposes only, not req'd -->
            <!-- defines limits for # of members permitted in list -->
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

XML:

```
<pfx:IDNAME>BOGUS-1</pfx:IDNAME>
<pfx:IDNAME>BOGUS-2</pfx:IDNAME>
<pfx:IDNAME>BOGUS-3</pfx:IDNAME>
<pfx:IDNAME>BOGUS-4</pfx:IDNAME>
<pfx:myLIST>BOGUS-1 BOGUS-2 BOGUS-3 BOGUS-4</pfx:myLIST>
```

Validation detects the following errors (based on restriction facets as shown):

- Quantity of list members exceeded; see min/max restriction facets
- List member not recognized as legal member, e.g., BOGUS-9 not in
  IDNAME set